# Data Plotting Library for Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, plot

There are several threads for data plotting libs for python 2.x.  What about python 3?  Matplotlib's website says "not python 3."

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374457/graphing-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 0):

Since latest SWIG support Python 3 then you can use [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net) with Python 3 too. MathGL is GPL cross-platform plotting library.